# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed' in Blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I keep getting this error when running my code:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: LykoDemo.Data.BookingService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: LykoDemo.Data.BookingService': Unable to resolve service for type 'LykoDemo.Data.LykoDemo.LykosqlContext' while attempting to activate 'LykoDemo.Data.BookingService'.)'

Inner Exception 1:

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: LykoDemo.Data.BookingService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: LykoDemo.Data.BookingService': Unable to resolve service for type 'LykoDemo.Data.LykoDemo.LykosqlContext' while attempting to activate 'LykoDemo.Data.BookingService'.

Inner Exception 2:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'LykoDemo.Data.LykoDemo.LykosqlContext' while attempting to activate 'LykoDemo.Data.BookingService'.

Getting lists from the database:

```
public class BookingService
{
    private readonly LykosqlContext _context;
    public BookingService(LykosqlContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<Booking>> GetBookingsAsync(string strCurrentUser)
    {
        return await _context.Booking
            .Where(x => x.UserName == strCurrentUser)
            .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<Room>> GetRoomsAsync() 
    {
        return await _context.Room.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Getting lists to my page:

```
@code {
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

List<Booking> bookings;
List<Room> rooms;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
{
    var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;

    rooms = await Service.GetRoomsAsync();
    bookings = await Service.GetBookingsAsync(user.Identity.Name);
}
}
```

And in my Startup.cs i added:

```
services.AddScoped<BookingService>();
```

If I remove the

```
services.AddScoped<BookingService>();
```

it runs, but I can't access the page. But if I remove that and

```
rooms = await Service.GetRoomsAsync();
bookings = await Service.GetBookingsAsync(user.Identity.Name);
```

everything runs smoothly, but I obviously can't populate my lists from the db. I'm sure I'm just making some rooky misstake, but any help is appreciated.

Edit:

My startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddScoped<BookingService>();
    }
```

Comment: add  services.AddScoped<BookingService>(); to your ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) methode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: LykoDemo.Data.BookingService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: LykoDemo.Data.BookingService': Unable to resolve service for type 'LykoDemo.Data.LykoDemo.LykosqlContext' while attempting to activate 'LykoDemo.Data.BookingService'.)'

This error message means you do not register the service(LykosqlContext).

Be sure register `LykosqlContext` like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    services.AddScoped<BookingService>();

    services.AddDbContext<LykosqlContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString")));
}
```

And your LykosqlContext just like below:

```
public class LykosqlContext : DbContext
{
    public LykosqlContext (DbContextOptions<LykosqlContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Booking> Booking { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Room { get; set; }
}
```

Connection string should be added in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "YourConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Comment: I added 
'services.AddDbContext<LykosqlContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString")));'

and that solved that issue. I'm now getting other issues thought, but at least this is solved. Thanks!